# Update WKWebView Cookie Values

Tags: ios, cookies, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, nshttpcookiestorage

My Requirement is to update the cookies that are set to `WKWebView`. I'm able to update the cookies in `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, but the same cookies are not reflected to `WKWebView` cookies(The update values are present in `NSHTTPCookieStorage` but are not set to `WKWebView`)

The following is code that i have used to set that cookies to AJAX calls.

```
NSString *strURL = DASHBOARDURL;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:url];

NSMutableString *script = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *cookieString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [cookieString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;", cookie.getCookieString]];
    [script appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.cookie='%@';",cookie.getCookieString]];

}
[request setValue:cookieString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
//cookies for further AJAX calls
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
WKUserScript *cookieInScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:script
                                                      injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
                                                   forMainFrameOnly:NO];
[userContentController removeAllUserScripts];

[userContentController addUserScript:cookieInScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];

webViewConfig.userContentController = userContentController;

CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect configuration:webViewConfig];
wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
[wkWebView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:wkWebView];
```

After updating the cookies, I tried to print the existing cookies in my NSHTTPCookieStorage, which shows the updated values.

```
NSLog(@"cookies:%@",[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]);
```

I also tried printing the script in `WKNavigationDelegate` after updating the cookies, but it shows old values.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler{
NSLog(@"Script: %@",[wkWebView.configuration.userContentController.userScripts firstObject].source);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixed my issue:

```
NSMutableString *script = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
    [script appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.cookie='%@';",cookie.getCookieString]];
}
[wkwebView evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id test, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"test");
}];


-(NSString *)getCookieString 
 {
 NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@;expiresDate=%@;path=%@;sessionOnly=%@;isSecure=%@",
        self.name,
        self.value,
        self.expiresDate,
        self.path ?: @"/",
        self.isSecure ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE",
        self.sessionOnly ? @"TRUE":@"FALSE"];
 return string;
}
```